# Check if value in array contains character [PHP]

Tags: php, character

Usually, this may seem pretty easy - I tied out some suggested solutions for this topic, but none of them seem to work - I seem to be missing something here...

I'm trying to look if `$Address['Address']` contains in its value a character. Let's say 'x'

```
(preg_match('/'.implode('|',$Address['Address']).'/', 'x', $matches))
```

or

```
if (strpos($Address['Address'], 'x') !== FALSE)
```

Doesn't seem to work the way I called it.

Comment: can you show the input string (addresses) ?

Comment: If you search for `x` in `$Address['Address']` your `preg_match` args are inverted. It's unclear what is in `$Address['Address']`: it is an array of single characters? Or it is a string? Or an array of strings?

Comment: Works for me using `strpos()`. Are you running this on a web server?

Comment: $Address['Address'] contains street & housenumber, as string. yes, it runs on an apache